# Terminal - current directory symbol

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Is there a symbol for the *current directory*?

For example instead of type the full path name for the current directory, e.g.:

> `cp /User/Name/f1/f2/ /User/Name/f3/f4/f5`

where `/User/Name/f1/f2/` is the current directory.

Is there any *symbol* that acts as `pwd`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply a `.` will act as the current working directory in bash

In this example you give

```
cp . /User/Name/f3/f4/f5
```

To note: this will not work, cp will need the `-r` parameter for copying directories

```
cp -r . /User/Name/f3/f4/f5
```

The current working directory can also be fetched with the `pwd` command, used as `$(pwd)` instead of `.` in this command